# iOS reqex not match this value 111111

Tags: ios, regex

```
#define REGEX_111111 @"^(?![a-zA-Z]{6})[0-9]{6}$"
```

How to write a regular expression that does not take the following values:
000000, 111111, 222222, 333333, 444444, 555555, 666666, 777777, 888888, 999999

Comment: Do you want to match everything except the same number 6 times in a row?

Comment: Yes, David, that's it.
In the code I have the following line

#define REGEX_111111 @"^(?![a-zA-Z]{6})[0-9]{6}$"
[self.textKundennummer addRegx:REGEX_111111 withMsg:@"Only numeric characters are allowed."];

but does not work.

Demo which was proposed by Avinash Raj, it works well on the Web at: https://regex101.com/r/iS8eA4/1

but does not work in IOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion like below,

```
@"^(?!([0-9])\1{5}$)[0-9]{6}$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iS8eA4/1)

This matches  a 6 digit number other than the number mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

try regex to get 8 same digital `"([0-9])\1\1\1\1\1"`

Comment: @tihoroot may be I didn't meet your question :) sorry